# Prove the following argument is valid by using the rule

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Been Trying To Solve This, Any Help?

$$p \to q$$

$$r \to u$$

$$p \land r$$

$$-------$$

$$\therefore \ q \land u \ \ \ \ $$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: 1) I have replaced your image by equivalent text 2) In your title you say "by using the rule":  which unique rule ? 3) Work first, and come back after having worked.